# Laravel no servidor Locaweb: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1

Tags: php, laravel

Estou hospedando na `Locaweb` e está dando este erro.

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
>   /home/storage/a/b7/b3/reciclaoleovegetal/public_html/public/index.php
>   on line 52
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /home/storage/a/b7/b3/reciclaoleovegetal/public_html/public/index.php
>   on line 52

Comment: Qual a versão do Laravel e qual a versão do PHP no teu locaweb?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento php está rodando o 7.1 é o laravel está na última versão 5.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mensagens como:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1
```

E:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
```

Indicam duas possibilidades, ou você editou algo que não devia e quebrou o script, ou você esta usando versão mais antiga do PHP que não suporta o Laravel.

Pela mensagem `Unexpected character in input: '\'` você deve estar usando **PHP 5.2**, pois namespaces só funcionam a partir do 5.3

Mas é importante saber que o uso de `::class`, que esta na linha 52 do index.php não funciona no nem no PHP 5.3:

[`$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php#L52)

Pra ter certeza da versão crie um arquivo chamado `info.php` na `public_html` e adicione isto:

```
<?php
echo 'Versão Atual do PHP: ' . phpversion();
```

Ele vai exibir os detalhes da versão do teu PHP, então terá certeza se é o 7.1, acaso for de fato o 7.1 então significa que ou você danificou o index.php ou foi falha no upload.

Se a versão estiver correta e o index.php estiver assim:

```
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Então o problema é no upload, se estiver usando Filezilla, talvez o teu FTP esteja quebrando algo ao tentar subir como ASCII, para que não perca dados faça o upload como binário, por exemplo no Filezilla vá em:

<kbd>Transfer</kbd> > <kbd>Transfer type</kbd> > e troque <kbd>Auto</kbd> por <kbd>Binary</kbd>

Como na imagem:

[image: filezilla]

Então faça o upload novamente.

Comment: Então, a versão do PHP é a 7.1, e ainda não alterei nenhum Script, fiz a instalação pelo composer e já apareceu este erro

Comment: @RobsonRodrigues veja a edição da resposta, se for de fato o 7.1 me confirma que eu tenho outra sugestão pra ti.

Comment: @RobsonRodrigues pela mensagem `Unexpected character in input: '\'` com certeza você esta usando PHP 5.2, isso porque no php5.2 ainda não existiam namespaces.

Comment: consegui resolver, o problema era na hospedagem, sempre que fazia a instalação do laravel via composer, a versão do php era alterada de 7.1 para 5.2, então era preciso alterar novamente a versão do php, só descobri graças aos posts

Comment: @RobsonRodrigues por favor então marque a resposta como correta, se não souber como leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635 - Obrigado!